# I am having an error in my passport local strategy that says password is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, es6-promise

I ve been trying to convert my code from callback to promise. But after getting my passport local strategy in promise I am having an error that says my password is not defined. Could you look into my code and detect where did I go wrong?

```
exports.newLocalStrategy=new localStrategy({
      usernameField: 'username',
      passwordField: 'password'
},(username,done)=>{
  User.findOne({username})
    .then(user =>{
      if(!user) return done(null, null, console.error('user or email incorrect'));
      return done(null, user);
    })
    .catch(err =>{
      return done(err, null);
  });
  comparePassword(password,user[0].password)
    .then(isMatch=>{
      if (isMatch) return (done, null);
  })
    .catch(err=>{
      console.error(err);
      return done(err, null);
    })
});
let comparePassword =new Promise((candidatePassword, hash, callback)=>{
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, (err, isMatch)=>{
    if (err) return callback(err);
    callback(null, isMatch);
    });
});
```

the error is coming from `comparePassword(password,user[0].password)`line

Comment: can you specify on which line you are getting the error?

Comment: in the comparePassword(password,user[0].password)

Comment: the password from here is not defined!

Comment: Well, that means the document it found in mongodb does not have `password` field. It might be named something else. Or you can check your `User` schema to make sure it contains the field `password` and not something like `pass`

Comment: Wait, you are using `findOne`, that won't return result in an array.

Comment: `return (done, null);` does not do what you think it does

Comment: @Bergi Okay, what should i use here to handle the error, I'm a super beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `findOne`. It will just return a single document object, and not an array.

So you don't have to `user[0].password`.

Instead, just use `user.password`.

Also, your `comparePassword` password needs to be executed after `findOne`. You need to put that call inside the callback of `findOne` where you have written `return done(null, user);`

You can read more about `findOne` [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne)

Comment: that's a huge mistake thanks for showing me that, But I dont think this is making the error. I have checked my schema and i've tried `user.password` as well, still I am having this issue

Comment: @ZeedTanue I'm not sure if you have seen the edit I made immediately after posting the answer. The `comparePassword` needs to be inside `findOne` callback.